# Flutterfire ios configuration issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

For some reason, I can't use the Flutterfire CLI to configure an ios app on firebase. I've done this before but this time I'm gettings this error

```
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create ios good_dreams (ios) --bundle-id=com.infatechnologies.good_dreams --json --project=good-dreams-app 
ERROR: Failed to create iOS app for project good-dreams-app. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

I've tried going through the debug.log file to see what's wrong and I saw a post request with and error code of 401 as a response.

```
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"method": "google.firebase.service.v1beta1.IosAppService.ListIosApps",
"service": "firebase.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}
```

What are these missing credentials? How do I get them? Here is the whole firebase-debug.log file:

```
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.658Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.660Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/firebase /Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase apps:create ios good_dreams (ios) --bundle-id=com.infatechnologies.good_dreams --json --project=good-dreams-app
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.660Z] CLI Version:   10.0.1
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.660Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.660Z] Node Version:  v12.18.1
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.661Z] Time:          Tue Feb 15 2022 15:41:11 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.661Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.708Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.708Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (aduhenry9@gmail.com)
[info] Create your IOS app in project good-dreams-app:
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:11.712Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/good-dreams-app/iosApps  
 {"displayName":"good_dreams (ios)","bundleId":"com.infatechnologies.good_dreams"}
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:12.192Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 {"vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","date":"Tue, 15 Feb 2022 15:41:12 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:12.193Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:12.194Z] HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
[debug] [2022-02-15T15:41:12.689Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
    at module.exports (/Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Request._callback (/Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:41:35)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to create iOS app for project good-dreams-app. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Comment: Please mark that answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the bundle id (ios) and package name (android) should be the same, they should not. The organisation might be the same but what comes last should not. That was the issue although it's not stated in any guide/tutorials I could find, not even in the error messages

Comment: I have many apps in the App store and Play store where they are exactly the same. I think something else solved your issue. For me the highest voted answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

to configure iOS:

```
flutterfire configure -i com.ios.bubdle
```

so add -i then your (ios) bundle id

from [CLI Commands](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli#commands)

Comment: For all who don't want to go read the official docs: the Android package name can be specified as follows:
`flutterfire configure -i your.ios.bundle-id.here -a your.android.package.name.here`

Answer (score 6):

Aha! I've found the answer. So for some reason, apple doesn't allow underscore("_") in bundleId names, change your bundleId to not use underscore and you'd be good to go.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try creating the IOS app manually via the Firebase Console (that's how I always do it).

[image]

[image]

Comment: That seems like a lot of work, the cli is way faster when you configure it once. Anyways I solved the issue, thanks for your suggestion